# MAC OS for Intel based PCs

Tags: windows, macos

I have an Intel dual core PC with 4GB of RAM and Graphics card. For on of my student Assignment I need to install Latest possible `MAC OS` on my system as a secondary OS.

Like on boot it asks me that which OS i want to boot with `Win 8.1` or `Mac Os..`

I searched on the internet and found two conflicting opinion some people said there are few MAC OS Version which can be directly installed on Intel PCs some says there aren't?

- I am here to get rid of the confusion that is an official latest
  possible MAC OS version for Intel based PCs?
- If not what are my
  options if I want to run MAC OS on my PC.

Please not that Virtualization options won’t work for me, it has to be working as full OS not an os inside another.

Comment: Your assignment forces you to spend money? Is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: In jurisdictions where EULAs can be legally enforced, giving you an assignment that requires you to install OS X on a PC would require you to break the law. So… I'd try to talk to your teachers about that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to imply you want to create a Hackintosh; questions about Hackintoshes are not permitted here.

Answer (score 3):

There's no Apple release of OSX which you can install on a non-Apple machine. You can sometimes set up a Hackintosh system, though. See http://www.hackintosh.com/. I haven't tried building a Hackintosh system, but my understanding is that it is flaky even if you take great pains to ensure you have only fully-supported hardware.

Comment: Just to be picky, yes there is, or at least was, namely OS X Server.

Comment: Phrased another way, Mac OS is officially supported only on Apple computers.  Installation on non-Apple devices is a violation of their EULA and technically illegal.  That said, many people go ahead and build systems with hardware that emulates Apple computers so that the OS can run on them. They are called Hackintosh computers.  Since they are not supported Apple updates break the OS ability to run on them so they are not the most stable systems.  You can search for Hackintosh to get sites that list the hardware most have used fairly successfully.

Answer (score 3):

There is one legal way in which to do this:

1. Sell the "dual core PC with 4GB of RAM and Graphics card"
2. Buy a Mac. Install OS X (native) and windows (use [bootcamp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/)).

There is no **legal** way for you to install OS X on non-Mac hardware.

For non-legal ways search on `hackintosh`, but no prof. will ask you to do this unless it is an ethics test.